# C# ASP.NET MVC Calculating sales tax

Tags: c#

I am trying to calculate sales tax in a view page and cannot seem to get it to work.

The code below is working other than producing a Total with sales Tax. The Sales Tax is singular and is not on every record. I basically just need to apply Tax to the subtotal and show the Total.

What I have tried:

```
totalOrder += (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice);

total = (totalOrder * 8%);
```

It does not like the 8%

Using a Variable

```
var tax = .08;
var tax = 8%

 ((totalOrder * tax) / 100);
```

All if the above gives errors - Cannot use * with decimal etc.

Below is the code for that section of the view. Thanks for your help

```
<tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceDetail)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Material)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                                    <td>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)</td>

                                    <td>@string.Format("{0:C2}", (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice))</td>
                                </tr>
                                totalOrder += (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice);

                                total = (totalOrder * 8%);
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Sub Total :</b> @string.Format("{0:C2}", totalOrder)</h5>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Tax :</b> 8%</h5>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Total Due :</b> @string.Format("{0:C2}", total)</h5>
```

I also am using this:

```
decimal totalOrder = 0;
decimal total = 0;
```

[Screen Shot of amounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKFYc.png)

[EDIT] Current code

```
decimal totalOrder = 100.1m;
decimal tax = .08m;
decimal total = totalOrder * (1.0m + tax);

<tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceDetail)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Material)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                                    <td>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)</td>

                                    <td>@string.Format("{0:C2}", (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice))</td>
                                </tr>
                                //totalOrder += (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice);


                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @{totalOrder += (Model.TotalCount * Model.PricePer);}
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Sub Total :</b> @string.Format("{0:C2}", totalOrder)</h5>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Tax :</b> 8%</h5>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Total Due :</b> @string.Format("{0:C2}", total)</h5>
```

Comment: for 8%, you can use total = (totalOrder * 0.08);

Comment: @Anu Viswan, If the variable names are proper, then your math only calculates the tax, and not the tax and the order.

Comment: @AnuViswan I tried that and get the same error as below in my comments. '*' cannot be used with decimal or double

Comment: Can you provide the type of `item.SellingPrice` please?

Comment: In SQL it is set as Money and on my end in my model it is set as decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nathan Werry I managed to get this problem resolved. I will explain what I did after each snippet.

Here is the code that was created for the Sales Tax:

```
decimal totalOrder = 0m;
decimal tax = .08m;
@{decimal totalTax = totalOrder * (tax);
  decimal total = totalOrder + totalTax;}
```

TotalOrder just reflects that the Quantity * SellingPrice is calculated below and there is no need to add anything to it.

Tax is tax at .08m

TotalTax is the TotalOrder * Tax

And finally you have to add the tax to the TotalOrder.

Below is the finished code for the foreach statement:

```
<tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceDetail)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Material)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                                    <td>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)</td>

                                    <td>@string.Format("{0:C2}", (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice))</td>
                                </tr>
                                totalOrder += (item.Quantity * item.SellingPrice);


                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    @{decimal totalTax = totalOrder * (tax);
                        decimal total = totalOrder + totalTax;}
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Sub Total :</b> @string.Format("{0:C2}", totalOrder)</h5>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Tax :</b> 8%</h5>
                    <h5 style="margin-left: 80%;"><b>Total Due :</b> @string.Format("{0:C2}", total)</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have two issues(and maybe one future issue), if I am interpreting your variable names correctly.

1. Your `total` variable is only getting set to the tax value, and not the `totalOrder` and the tax
2. `var tax = 8%` is not valid c#, you need to use a decimal like `var tax = .08`
3. Another thing to keep in mind, which I do not think you have gotten to yet, is rounding issues with sub cent numbers.

The code should be something like:

```
decimal totalOrder = 100.01m;
decimal tax = .08m;
decimal total = totalOrder * (1.0m + tax);
```

Comment: So I tried var  tax = .08; with total *= totalOrder + tax I am getting an error that says Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double' and also what you have in your code. I am getting an error that says Operator '*=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double' The decimal issue was an issue with what I have in the question also

Comment: I added a screen shot of the totals with your code. Not exactly right. subtotal is more than it should be and with tax its less..

Comment: Ah! Seems like I overlooked another item of concern. You calculate your final total in each line item. That should be moved outside the loop.

Comment: I moved it out of the loop and it did not change the pricing, still the same prices that I have in the pic.

Comment: Please update your question with the current code set, so that I can further assist.

Comment: Also with decimal totalOrder = 0; I get the correct subtotal.

Comment: I have done my best with answering the question about how to calculate the tax and the total that includes tax in the types that were provided. It is hard to provide an extensive solution that fits your whole application when only snippets are included. Now we are running into issues with how to apply my answer to code snippets that are not included in the original question, and are not part of the original question.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, However that is really all the code there is. I am pulling the information onto the view from a view model. I could post the view model but I doubt there is anything in there that would enlighten the situation. All the current code that is on the page produces everything fine I decided to add sales tax and ran into issues. The thing is, the sales tax doesn't even matter for everyone this will only calculate if the customer has not uploaded their sales and use tax form. I am business to business and most are exempt.